# Unable to fetch DOM elements Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, handlebars.js

I have loaded an HTML page and ran some javascript code on the console. Can any one explain me the behavior.

`document.getElementById('tiers__0__.threshold1')` gives me

```
<input id=​"tiers__0__.threshold1" type=​"text" class=​"field  mandatory" data-name=​"tiers__0__.threshold1" data-domain=​"ANY" name=​"dynamicValues['tiers__0__.threshold1']​" value=​"5" maxlength readonly>​
```

`document.getElementById('tiers__0__.threshold1').value` gives me

```
""
```

`document.getElementById('tiers__1__.threshold1')` gives me

```
<input id=​"tiers__1__.threshold1" type=​"text" class=​"field " data-name=​"tiers__1__.threshold1" data-domain=​"ANY" name=​"dynamicValues['tiers__1__.threshold1']​" value=​"10" maxlength readonly>​
```

`document.getElementById('tiers__1__.threshold1').value` gives me

```
"10"
```

Why is the 1st DOM element not giving me the value. Both the DOM elements have same structure. I generate them using Handlebars "each" property.

P.S. I know sometimes the DOT in an id creates issue. Even tried using escape sequence (//). Nothing worked. Tried Jquery also

`$('#tiers__0__\\.threshold1').val()` (Used double slash. SO just displays 1) gives me

```
""
```

Question Updated after more  research.

The earlier test was done on Chrome browser but after doing it on Firefox got different result.

$('#tiers__0__.threshold1')

```
Object[input#tiers__0__.threshold1.field property value = "" attribute value = "5"]
```

Can anyone explain what is property value and why it it getting appended only for my 1st text box as null. Is their any way i can make this same as my attribute value or i can remove it completely.

Note -: I am using handlebar template for rendering a JSON object. I have checked both the JSON and Handlebar consists of uniform data. i have a input tag which looks like this

```
<input id="{{name}}{{#if count}}{{count}}{{/if}}" type="text" class="field {{#if this.mandatory}} mandatory{{/if}}" data-name="{{name}}" data-domain="{{domain}}" name="{{bindingName}}" value={{val}} maxlength="{{this.maxLength}}" {{#if this.locked}}readOnly{{/if}}/>
```

It renders perfect for other values in the for loop,only screws the 1st one with an extra property

Comment: [CNR](http://jsfiddle.net/mNLHU/)

Comment: Guys, even i know that should work, buts it not working and that is why this question is here. I am using Handlebar templates to render the page and passing a JSON payload. It should display 3 rows with values. It just display 2nd & 3rd with the value, noot just the 1st one.

Comment: When you copy-paste your code to fiddle, you get some extra characters there in HTML. See if you have copied the code from some funny encoded file.

Comment: nopes, its a production code which has suddenly started behaving differently. i just tried to see the value so i manually wrote those document.getElementById lines

Comment: there are problems with your " characters they are not recognized as ". rewrite it

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' Can you please provide more details. i did not get your context.